# What percentage of the capacity of dam A is the capacity of dam B

Tags: calculus, percentages

Dam A, at full volume, has the capacity of 3907,95 gigalitres.
Dam B, at full volume, has the capacity of 3038 gigalitres. What percentage of the capacity of  dam A is the capacity of dam B?

3907,95:3038=1,286  dam A is 1,286 times larger that dam B.

Comment: This is correct. Multiply by 100 for the percentage.

Comment: $3038/3907,95 \times 100\%=?$

Comment: `dam A is 1,286 times larger that dam B` That's correct, but it's not what the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

The percentage of $B$ wrt $A$ is $\dfrac{B}{A}$. Maybe the question not so clear, but this is what they ask. Which part of $A$ is $B$, so the correct result is

$\dfrac{3038}{3907,95}\approx 0.7774$

Better specify that the percentage has no unit, no measure: it is just the ratio of two homogeneous quantities

Another specification. Not always the percentage is written in $\%$

the ratio we found before $\dfrac{B}{A}=0.7774$ ***may*** be written as $77,74\%$

Often percentage is left as a decimal. In probability, for instance.

In other contexts it can be used a "permileage" for instance the rate of babies who dies in the first year of life in a country in a specific year is measured in per thousand rate using this symbol $‰ $

Hope this helps